# Portlet doesn't process action phase

Tags: java, spring, liferay, portlet, spring-webflow

I have a portlet basically simple form. When i enter on that page with form directly for the first time and submit it, my page is only reloaded. On second submit it works.

Next case is, when i enter on that page from another page by link. It works on first time.

**We using:**

- java 8
- Liferay 6
- spring-webflow 2.4.4
- spring 4.3.12

Can somebody help me? It's looks like some cookie/session problem in Liferay.

Comment: Liferay 6 spans from 6.0.0 released back in 2010 to 6.2.5 released couple a weeks ago. You need to be more specific about your version.

Also if would be helpful to provide the URL (with parameters) the form is submitted to in both (when it works and when it doesn't) cases.

Comment: We using Liferay 6.2.10.7, now i find that, portlet failed on auth_token, but only on first time.  WARN  [default task-13][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:630] Reject process action

Comment: Have you seen https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/42032859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Liferay(6.2.10.7) bug, liferay is incompatible with jBoss(wildfly-10.1.0). They said, they will fix it asap.